# Won't pass emissions, Bad ECU?

Tags: fuel-system, electronic-control-module, emissions, acura, integra

[image]So, Last year my 94 Acura Integra AT passed emissions by the skin of its teeth, this year it won't pass, I have noticed in past year and half that dropped from around 30mpg to about 15mpg. Some times last year I would be parked idleing and everything would be normal, car would just shut off for no reason. Also when I start the car you can tell it is dumping fuel as the engine shakes and has rough idle on start, sometimes it takes more then 10 seconds to start when turning the key. I have replaced everything on the car but the ECU, I have the following new:

- Catalytic Converter
- Spark plugs
- Plug wires
- Distributor
- Fuel filter
- Fuel pressure regulator
- Injectors
- TPS sensor
- Ambient air temp sensor
- O2 sensor
- Complete intake clean and new gaskets
- New air filter
- Pcv valve
- IAC
- New timing belt and timing adjusted accordingly
- Valve adjustment to OE spec

And whatever else there is.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you have the data on the emissions readout, that may be helpful in diagnosing your issue. From your huge drop in fuel mileage, I'd assume your HC's are out of this world.

Comment: CO levels are too high.

Comment: Have you read your codes?

Comment: OBD1, did paperclip method and no codes.

Comment: @BrandonBeecher - Yes, but what were the numbers? All three, not just CO.

Comment: what was the lamda?

Comment: Since having had these issues, have you reset the ECU at any point? (Note: by “resetting” I would include having the battery disconnected for >5 min.)

Comment: Many times been reset.

Comment: I will get those numbers from emission later and post them.

Comment: I posted the numbers in a picture above, those are results from test.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Picture

Comment: I cannot see images here at work, so will have to look when I get home. Someone might beat me to the punch, so hopefully it will help in the diagnosis.

Comment: Let me know please

Comment: Have you checked the fuel pressure over time after you've shut the car down? Have you cleaned the EGR and passages?

Comment: There is no EGR on this car, fuel pressure i have never checked.

Answer (score 2):

Does it show a check engine light (CEL)? Search for Integra CEL ECU Codes and you will find instructions to show any system codes and take appropriate action.

If you aren't getting a CEL then replacing the ECU won't hurt. Very weird symptoms could be ignition or fuel. Difficult to imagine what else it could be based on what you've already done.

The next step is to get the factory service manual and test all the sensors for operation within specification. Just because parts are new doesn't mean they are operating within spec.

Good luck!

Comment: No CEL, I don't know why an ECU would fail if it's not getting wet or something to damage it.

Comment: Vibration can damage it ...